# With Javascript use a for loop to sum numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to find a way to sum all the numbers that have been added to an array. I believe this should work:

```
   var total = 0;

   for (var i  = 0; i < totalPrice.length; i++);

   total  += totalPrice[i];
   document.getElementById("displayPrice").innerHTML = total;
```

But total comes out as a NaN.

This is an example of my code in JSFiddle, if you add the item twice the value gets pushed into the array, what am I doing wrong with the for loop?

https://jsfiddle.net/bgv5s9re/2/

Comment: Typo: Remove the semicolon after the `for(...); <---`. That's an empty statement, which became the body of the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. And just FYI, you get `NaN` because `i` is out of bounds, so you're doing `total += undefined`, since out of bounds array access produces the `undefined` value.

Answer (score 5):

You could use brackets

```
  var total = 0;

   for (var i  = 0; i < totalPrice.length; i++){

      total  += totalPrice[i];

   }
   document.getElementById("displayPrice").innerHTML = total;
```